# fit syntax from bash to ksh

Tags: bash

the following syntax work in bash but bot work on ksh script

```
   [[ " $LINE_FROM_FILE " == *[![:alnum:]]Validation[![:alnum:]]* ]] && print "find Validation word"
```

can someone have idea how to change the syntax in order to fit also ksh script

remark: the target of this syntax to verify if Validation word exist in $LINE_FROM_FILE

```
    example: LINE_FROM_FILE=" file dir Validation 1283474"
```

Comment: It works for me… `ksh> LINE_FROM_FILE='Validation'` followed by `ksh> [[ " $LINE_FROM_FILE " == *[![:alnum:]]Validation[![:alnum:]]* ]] && print "find Validation word"` outputs `find Validation word`. If all else fails, try the `=~` regex comparison.

Comment: And your updated example (`LINE_FROM_FILE=" file dir Validation 1283474"`) works, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on my Linux machine
Maybe ksh version not higher enough  , on other update Linux machine is work file
lidia

Comment: What does `ksh --version` give you on each machine?